# Setting value of the structure via fmt.Sscan

Tags: go, reflection

I want to synchronize state between `map[string]string` and custom Go structure and came to a conclusion that simplest way to parse it is to use `fmt.Sscan` for fields.

Unfortunately, direct approach is not working ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QaRuinJ_dv)):

```
var S struct{ I int }

f := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(&S)).Field(0)
fmt.Sscan("10", f.Interface())
fmt.Println(S) // {0}
```

Introducing an intermediate value and using `Set()`, however, solves the issue:

```
nv := reflect.New(f.Type())
fmt.Sscan("10", nv.Interface())
f.Set(reflect.Indirect(nv))
fmt.Println(S) // {10}
```

I wonder why the first approach didn't work. Isn't `Interface()` returns a kind of reference to a field which can be used to change its value?

Comment: Please explain why it is not appropriate to use `fmt.Sscan("10", &S.I)` (which works as expected).

Comment: @KavehShahbazian because type of structure is not known

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Interface()` method returns the value, not a reference to the value.  Take the address (by calling [`Addr()`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Addr)) of the field to scan directly to the field:

```
var S struct{ I int }
f := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(&S)).Field(0)
fmt.Sscan("10", f.Addr().Interface())  
fmt.Println(S) // {0}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6_4DjiFZB2